# Possible null reference return ( code 5.0 to 7.0)

Tags: c#, .net, model-view-controller

I am working on 5.0 in which below function is working fine.

```
public async Task<Student> GetStudentAsync(Guid studentId)
{
    return await context.Student.Include(nameof(Gender)).Include(nameof(Address))
                .FirstOrDefaultAsync(x => x.Id == studentId); 
}
```

Here few more code unable to share all

```
 public async Task<bool> UpdateStudent(Guid Id, string ImageUrl)
        {
            var student = await GetStudentAsync(Id);

            if (student != null)
            {
                student.ImageUrl = ImageUrl;
                await context.SaveChangesAsync();
                return true;
            }
            return false;
        }
```

But while using the same code .net 7.0 unable to perform operation. Please suggest.

Comment: This isn't MVC code , it's not *proper* EF Core code either (why `nameof`? are `Gender` and `Address` classes? ) and it's unclear what's throwing because the exception itself is missing.  The problem isn't EF Core 7 or .NET 7, they don't have "so many bugs".

Comment: @Serge the people using .NET 7 or EF Core 7 would disagree. The reason to bypass it is because it's a Current instead of a Long-Term-Support version, not bugs

Comment: The query itself wouldn't work in EF Core 5 either, unless `Gender` and `Address` were classes. If they were, the normal way to eagerly load them is `Include(student=>student.Gender)`, not passing the name of a class that may or may *not* be an attribute of `Student`. Using classes for `Gender` and `Address` is unusual, unless they're owned types stored in the `Student` table. Is that the case?

Comment: If `Gender` and `Address` are owned types `Include` isn't needed. EF Core 6 [introduced breaking changes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/what-is-new/ef-core-6.0/breaking-changes) in owned types. It's hard to say if one of these applies as the relevant types (Student, Gender, Address) and DbContext configuration are missing

Comment: Gender and Address were classes, and working fine in 5.0

Comment: You mean in EF Core 5? I already linked to the breaking changes introduced in EF Core 6. The way you use `Include` is unusual and unsafe. Post enough code so *others* can reproduce the problem.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos It is my personal experience. I spent the whole day trying to make my code working in EF7 but in the end gave up and restored EF6

Comment: _"But while using the same code .net 7.0 unable to perform operation"_ - can you please elaborate WHY you can't perform it?

Comment: @Serge and I've been using it for over a year without problems. It has no show-stopper, critical bugs. Breaking changes aren't bugs [and they're documented, along with fixes and workarounds](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/what-is-new/ef-core-7.0/breaking-changes)

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Maybe you are right. But I was unlucky. I could not even to connect to MS Server after trying all possible and not possible fixes and workarounds. I've been working with MS SQL Server for more than 20 years and never had such problems before

Comment: If all you want is to change a property, there's no reason to use `Include`. Doing so simply wastes IO. You could write `var student = await context.Students.FirstOrDefaultAsync(...); if (student!=null){ student.ImageUrl=...; await context.SaveChangesAsync();}`. Or you could return immediatelly if `student` is null. You can't claim that `FirstOrDefaultAsync` isn't working in EF Core 7 so the real problem is the named passed to `Include` and the DbContext configuration

Comment: @Serge if you were working for 20 years you'd know there's no way in h***** that EF Core  7 would be released without being able to connect to SQL Server. If you got issues with TLS, it's not EF Core 7. The change is in Microsoft.Data.SqlClient which requires encryption by default. That is the very first breaking change in the EF Core 7 list. The fix is to either set `TrustServerCertificate=True` so at least you get encryption, or install a proper certificate in SQL Server. Or you can set `Encrypted=False` to get unencrypted connections. Which isn't a great idea

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Do you really think that I have not tried all of these and even much more?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems that during migration you also have enabled [nullable reference types](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/nullable-references). `FirstOrDefaultAsync` will return `null` if enumeration yields no results (hence there is no student with passed id). You can either disable NRTs or fix the method signature `Task<Student>` -> `Task<Student?>` (which makes more sense based on the following null check):

```cs
public async Task<Student?> GetStudentAsync(Guid studentId)
{
    // ...
}
```

And the warning/error in the title should go away.